# Shared NuGet Repository

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package-restore

We have the following branches within subversion (Development, QA, Trunk).

There is a NuGet configuration file setup within the root of each branch.

- Development/NuGet.config
- QA/NuGet.config
- Trunk/NuGet.config

Each configuration file has the repositoryPath pointing to the same folder within its own branch.  We also have a private source setup for each environment in packageSources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="shared\NuGet\Packages" />
  </config>

  ... 

  <packageSources>
    <add key="Private Source" value="\\Private\Development" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />        
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Packages are installed locally when installing the NuGet package to Development/Shared/NuGet/Packages and packages are restored to their proper environment when running the restore command.

Our Continuous Integration Server (Jenkins) uses nuget restore in order to pull down the missing references.  Therefore the nuget packages are pulled down into their relative workspace folder.

Example:
C:/Builds/Workspace/ProjectA/Development/Shared/NuGet/Packages
C:/Builds/Workspace/ProjectA/QA/Shared/NuGet/Packages
C:/Builds/Workspace/ProjectA/Trunk/Shared/NuGet/Packages

For each project that has a NuGet reference to LibraryX, the NuGet package is pulled down into its own workspace.  Meaning we will have hundreds of copys of the DLL on our build server fore each environment for each project.

Example:
C:/Builds/Workspace/**ProjectA**/Development/Shared/NuGet/Packages/LibraryX.dll
C:/Builds/Workspace/**ProjectA**/QA/Shared/NuGet/Packages/LibraryX.dll
C:/Builds/Workspace/**ProjectA**/Trunk/Shared/NuGet/Packages/LibraryX.dll

C:/Builds/Workspace/**ProjectB**/Development/Shared/NuGet/Packages/LibraryX.dll
C:/Builds/Workspace/**ProjectB**/QA/Shared/NuGet/Packages/LibraryX.dll
C:/Builds/Workspace/**ProjectB**/Trunk/Shared/NuGet/Packages/LibraryX.dll

Ideally we would like one central repository while developing on our local machine and one central repository for the build server so the developer can work locally without having be connected to the build server.  They can live independently.

I thought of specifying the full path but the paths are different from the local machine to the CI server.  Thought about using a share, but then the developer can't work locally when not connected to our server.

How do we setup a central repository (not source) for the NuGet packages to get pulled down to?